# Getting the centroid of each polygon from a GeoJson multipolygon in d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, geojson

I'm using d3.js for a non contiguous cartogram where countries are scaled depending on some data. I'm scaling from the centroid of each country/path in the svg generated from a GeoJson file, but this doesn't look good for countries described as a multipolygon, like the USA or Canada.

I would like to find the centroid of each polygon forming a multipolygon, so I can rescale without translating them. For example, when using the centroid of the USA, Alaska moves towards the right (in a mercator projection) while the rest moves up. Ideally, Alaska would be scaled from its own centroid, so it would stay in the same position.

Is it possible to iterate through each polygon in a multipolygon feature and get its centroid?

Thanks!

Comment: You would need to iterate over the `.coordinates` member of your multipolygon.

Comment: I haven't tried scaling down, but I made bars appear at states centroid here: http://vida.io/documents/s5qo5Gwrct5HNxAD2

Comment: @PhuocDo You are getting one centroid per state/polygon, while I'm looking for getting every centroid for each state. Like getting the centroid of each island in Alaska.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff So it would be neccessary to manually calculate each centroid and store as an attribute of each polygon? How would you calculate it? Thanks

Comment: As I've said, a multipolygon consists of a list of polygons which you can access through `.coordinates`. For each of these, you should be able to calculate the centroid in the same way as you do in general.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I'm trying to create a path for each polygon inside a multipolugon like this:

 `code`
d3.json("world.json", function(collection) {
 feature = interior.selectAll("path")
 .data(collection.features.geometry.coordinates)
 .enter().append("path")
 .attr("d",d3.geo.path().projection(projection))});
`code`

But I get the error TypeError: collection.features.geometry is undefined

Comment: So the arrays of coordinates aren't GeoJSON features anymore and therefore you can't draw them directly with `d3.geo.path`. Extracting the polygons would be only for the purpose of getting the centroid. Do you have a complete working example somewhere?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I have uploaded here [link](http://www.nachocossio.com/d3/) Just need to Click 'Find'. Possible Cross origin error if using other browser than Safari. I use Firefox and CORS plug in. Thanks

Comment: You probably want to construct a polygon for each member of coordinates and use [its `centroid` method](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Polygon-Geom#wiki-centroid) to get the centroid. The actual drawing would be independent of that.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I see, thanks! Once a path is added to the svg using all points in the multipolygon, is it possible to identify the different polygons to scale according to the calculated centroids?

Comment: If you simply iterate over them, the indices should match, but you can of course store something like an ID with the computed centroid (or even add that information to the original feature).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I decided to split multipolygons in polygons by iterating over geometry.coordinates as @LarsKotthoff mentioned. With these polygons I created a new array of features with no Multipolygon types in it. Paths are added to the svg from this array, resulting in several polygons having the same id and name, i.e., several polygons for Canada with the same country abbreviation.

Thus you can keep using d3's path.centroid() to get the centroid of each polygon.